# Combine two data ranges into one range (Google Drive Excel)

Tags: excel, dataset, google-sheets, frequency

Hi there I am looking to combine two data ranges/arrays into one in order to feed them into excel `FREQUENCY` function.

Example:
First data range - `B5:F50`
Second data range - `J5:N50`
Bins data range - `I5:I16`
Function definition - `FREQUENCY(data_array; bins_array)`

Basically I am lazy and I don't want to reshuffle my excel script to spit out both datasets side by side so that I can reference them using something like `B5:K50` range. Is there any way I can combine both datasets into `data_array` using some kind of formula? Maybe to end up with something along the line of `=FREQUENCY((B5:F50,J5:N50); I5:I16)` ?

BTW: Either of

```
=FREQUENCY(B5:F50; I5:I16)
=FREQUENCY(J5:N50; I5:I16)
```

work just file on their own for me.

**Update**

[Actual formula definition `FREQUENCY(data, classes)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094286)

**2013 MS Excel (unrelated)**

[image]

Comment: Sorry I've update the title so not to confuse people with MS Excel.

Comment: Re the screenshot - yes, it **highlights** the correct ranges, but try putting some values in column F - they will be included in the results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MS Excel `FREQUENCY` function accepts a **"union"** as the first argument, i.e. a list of references separated by commas and enclosed in parentheses e.g.

`=FREQUENCY((B5:F50,J5:N50),I5:I16)`

Note: the "bins array" can also be a union if required

In "Google sheets" I don't think the same thing is possible - there may be a clever workaround, but I'm not aware of it

Comment: I've tried all sorts of combinations with commas, colons, semi-colons, sum(), etc, etc before posting. It just will not work for me :c

Comment: The above doesn't work for you either? Note that it's slightly different than the version you suggested in your question - a semi-colon between the two ranges. What country do you have set for regional settings?

Comment: If it "doesn't work" then in what way? - is the formula not accepted, do you get an error or just the wrong result? - of course `FREQUENCY` function needs to be entered in a range of cells or used appropriately within another function

Comment: Judging by Russian interface I'd say its in Russian. BTW I am using in Google Drive Excel not MS Excel. MS version uses comma as a separator between data_array and bins_array and it likes colon as a union e.g. ``=FREQUENCY((A1:E25:G1:K25),M1:M50)``. The same doesn't work in Google Drive.

Comment: Using (A1:E25:G1:K25) in Excel doesn't actually work to give you a union of A1:E25 and G1:K25, it gives you the same as A1:K25 and therefore includes column F - to use a union in Excel you need the relevant separator between the ranges as per my answer so you'd need this assuming comma separators - `=FREQUENCY((A1:E25,G1:K25),M1:M50)` - but "Google Drive" is not the same as MS Excel - I'm not aware that you can use a union there

Comment: Hrm, I have to disagree with you there. If my eye do not deceive me both ``=FREQUENCY((A1:E25:G1:K25),M1:M50)`` and ``=FREQUENCY((A1:E25,G1:K25),M1:M50)`` highlight the same data regions in MS Excel and give the same result. It might have something to do with the fact that I have 2013 Excel here. But regardless, neither of those formulas work in Google Excel.

Comment: I edited my answer - my solution works in MS Excel but I don't know a way to do this in google sheets, sorry

Comment: I don't think you are correct re that syntax - I am using Excel 2010 at the moment but I'd be amazed if it's any different in Excel 2013. It's not restricted to FREQUENCY function, try using this formula `=SUM(A1:A10:F1:F10)` leave columns A and F blank and put some values in B1, D3 etc. That formula will sum all those values because it's actually the same as `=SUM(A1:F10)`

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. But, but, I think they changed it cause I am sure thats not the way it behaves in 2010 (image linked).

Comment: Thank you for trying buddy. I know that it helps to poke the right people so I think I'll rephrase my question a little better and try again.

Comment: No problem - If you use `=SUM(A1:A10:F1:F10)` you may find that it only **highlights** `A1:A10` and `F1:F10` but it **sums** everything in `A1:F10` - FREQUENCY is the same.

Answer (score 5):

The Using Arrays page has some details that worked for me:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en

It says:

"You can join multiple ranges into one continuous range using this same punctuation, which works the same way as VMERGE. For example, to combine values from `A1-A10` with the values from `D1-D10`, you can use the following formula to create a range in a continuous column: `={A1:A10; D1:D10}`"

I have two named ranges, so I was able to use `{namedRange1;namedRange2}` and it gave me one continuous range.